# Which rpm´s should i run my Turbo Diesel at?

Tags: ford, diesel, turbocharger, mondeo

So this question has been itching in me for quite a while but i´ve been too lazy ask.
I have a Ford Mondeo 2005 2.2 TDCI and my question is how high or low rpm´s should i be driving my car(i know it´s kinda stupid question but still). 
I´ve always driven my car around 1500 and always change gear around 2000-2300 but the turbo always kicks in around 2000 and when sometimes i need to accelerate fast(note that i´m driving on 1500 rpm´s) the turbo kicks in later and sometimes forces me to wait behind a red light.What i´m interested is should i be driving my car around 2000rpms and does the fuel consumption gets worse aswell?

Comment: just downshift when you need to

Answer (score 1):

Have the same duratorq in my car (2.2 diesel), I use nearly the full rev range occasionally from 1000 to 3500 especially when overtaking, cruise is often around 2000 - depends on whether 4th, 5th or 6th though. Using the turbo is fine and I am pleased with the fuel consumption - same as a smaller car with less power...

Comment: ok thats good to know thank you. i´ll just cruise around 2000 then because sometimes i need that extra power